# Loading external JARs

Tags: java, eclipse

I am making a launcher that needs to find JARs that have a class annotated with an `@Program` annotation. But whenever I load the JAR classes, it can never find the annotation on any of the classes from any JAR.

If I have the classes in the launcher JAR, they show up. But when coming from an external JAR, they don't show. `getAnnotations()` shows nothing. Even `getClassesAnnotatedWith(Program.class)` gives nothing.

What am I missing?

The annotation is in it's own class alongside (same package) the main class of the program.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Type (ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Program {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For handling annotations correctly, their class files must be in the class path of the running program. If the JVM loads a class with annotations that are not found in the class path, these annotations are silently dropped (other than classes that are not found). In that case you also will not find them anymore with reflective accesses.

So make sure, the annotation' class files are in the class path.

Comment: The annotation class is in the launcher jar. Do I need to explicitly load that class on program startup?

Comment: Show the annotation source, please.

Comment: Just put the annotation class in the question.